# How to create a new df out of results of the loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm using for loop to print some parameters I collect daily. My script bellow:

```
for i in pd.date_range('2017-02-01', periods=380, freq='D'):
   results_df = get_instances_for_date(i).as_matrix()
   row = results_df[0]
   print(i, row[0], row[1], row[2])
```

The output:

```
2017-02-01 12:00:00    332   722   2.2893
2017-02-02 12:00:00    332   722   2.2893
2017-02-03 12:00:00    332   722   2.2893
2017-02-04 12:00:00    332   722   2.2893
2017-02-05 12:00:00    332   722   2.2893
2017-02-06 12:00:00    331   720   2.2890
2017-02-07 12:00:00    331   720   2.2890
2017-02-08 12:00:00    334   726   2.3049
2017-02-09 12:00:00    334   726   2.3049
2017-02-10 12:00:00    334   726   2.3049
...................    ...   ...   ......
2018-02-15 12:00:00    410   813   4.0213
```

How should I create df for these results so I can work with it further?

Answer (score 1):

Try the below. The trick is to append results in a list and then aggregate them at the end. Code is untested as you haven't supplied sample data, but the principle is correct.

```
import pandas as pd

lst = []
appender = lst.append

for i in pd.date_range('2017-02-01', periods=380, freq='D'):
    results_df = get_instances_for_date(i).as_matrix()
    row = results_df[0]
    appender([i, row[0], row[1], row[2]])

df = pd.DataFrame(lst, columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your loop, initialise an empty dataframe, and then use the [append](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) method:

```
df = pd.Dataframe()
for item in items:
    row = something_that_returns_a_list()
    df = df.append(row)
```